# Writing a SQL function that returns a function and get `Expecting EXTERNAL` near 'begin'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

The code tries to get all numeric columns and then returns the list as a new table but I am getting stuck at the `begin` part. The error is: `Expecting EXTERNAL near 'begin'.`

```
go
create function get_num_col(@table_name varchar(255))
returns table ( column_name varchar(255) )
as
begin
   select
      column_name
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
   where TABLE_NAME = table_name
       and data_type in ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT', 'DOUBLE')
   return
end
```

Comment: What DBMS is this? Please tag your request accordingly.

Comment: SQL 2019, thanks I;ll add that to question

Comment: Check the official documentation - it looks like you are mixing inline table valued function syntax with multi-statement table valued function syntax

Comment: This one for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-creating-an-inline-table-valued-function

Comment: Side note: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is for compatibility only, you should use `sys.columns` and `sys.types` instead. Also object and column names should be `sysname` which is the same as `nvarchar(128)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax you need for your function is:

```
create function get_num_col(@table_name sysname)
returns table 
as
return
   select column_name
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
   where TABLE_NAME = @table_name and data_type in ('NUMERIC', 'FLOAT', 'REAL', 'DECIMAL', 'INT', 'SMALLINT', 'TINYINT');
```

Note the data type should be `sysname` which is a synonym for `nvarchar(128)`

Also note presumably you intended "numeric" and "decimal". See the [`sys.types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) table.

In addition, as mentioned in the comments, in SQL Server you should use `sys.columns` to determine the column properties where you can also use the `type_name()` function.

For example:

```
select t.[Name]
from sys.tables t 
where exists (
  select * from sys.columns c
  where t.object_id = c.object_id
    and Type_Name(c.system_type_id) in (
      'bigint',
      'decimal',
      'float',
      'int',
      'numeric',
      'real',
      'smallint',
      'tinyint'
   )
);
```